# WPF DataGrid Get Row Item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

i am new to wpf, i have datagrid as follows,

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dg1" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Articles}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel has property

```
public IEnumerable<Article> Articles
{
    get
    {
       return _ArticleList;
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the selected item, following code returns error.
Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'Article'.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Article Article = (Article)this.dg1.SelectedItems;
}
```

Please any suggestions how to implement the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

DataGrid.SelectedItems is an IList. if you want just the Selected One use DataGrid.SelectedItem <-- without s :)

if you want to set the SelectedItem via Binding:

```
public Article SelectedArticle
{
    set
    {
       this._selectedArticle= value;
       OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArticle");
    }
    get
    {
       return _selectedArticle;
    }
}
```

XAml

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

or as CommandParameter for Button with ICommand

```
<Button Command="{Binding EditDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyGridCtrl, Path=MyDataGrid.SelectedItem}"/>
```

or all SelectedItems for Button with ICommand

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyGridCtrl, Path=MyDataGrid.SelectedItems}" >
```

Comment: You don't specify what `MyGridCtl` is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if items are selected:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if(this.dg1.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
         Article article = (Article)this.dg1.SelectedItems;
     }
}
```

Comment: the error is not because of variable, its a typing mistake, in code i use __article

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works...

> Article _article =
>   ((dgReferences.SelectedItem as
>   DataGridRow).Item as Article);

Regards
ArunDhaJ